# Error Calling unknown method: omgdef\multilingual\MultilingualQuery::sort()?

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions

Good afternoon, help me figure it out, using the OmgDef/yii2-multilingual-behavior extension, swears at this line:

```
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $data = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => FaqLang::find()->multilingual()->sort(), //error here
        ]);
        return $this->render('index', [
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
```

My overridden model that stores the sort() method

```
<?
namespace admin\base;

/**
 * Base active query class for models
 * @package admin\base
 */
class ActiveQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
    /**
     * Order by order_num
     * @return $this
     */
    public function sort()
    {
        $this->orderBy(['order_num' => SORT_ASC]);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are implementing the `sort` method in one class but calling it in another. Since you are using an ActiveDataProvider, why not use its `sort` property? It seems like it would be an easier way to do what you are trying.

Comment: @Raul Sauco Thank you I will try

Comment: @Raul Sauco I used the following construction in the model:

Comment: `foreach(FaqLangModel::find()->multilingual()->select(['id', 'question', 'answer'])->orderBy(['order_num' => SORT_ASC])
                        ->all() as $item){
                $items[] = new FaqObject($item);
            }`

Comment: And in the controller this:

Comment: `$data = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => FaqLang::find()->multilingual(),
            'sort' => [
                'defaultOrder' => ['order_num' => SORT_ASC],
                'attributes' => [
                    'id', 'question', 'answer'
                ],
            ],
        ]);`

Comment: Now an error has occurred 500 due to which the page has completely stopped loading.

Comment: i just posted an answer, easier to see edits there than in the comments.

Comment: Did you check the debug logs when you got the 500 error? It looks like the error should come from trying to use `attributes` on the `ActiveDataProvider` but you should be able to find more information on the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `sort` property of the `ActiveDataProvider`.

```
$data = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => FaqLang::find()
        ->multilingual()
        ->select(['id','question','answer']),
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => ['order_num' => SORT_ASC],
    ],
]);
```

To select columns use the `select()` method of the `ActiveQuery` object.

If you are using `GridView` to display results, you can also use it's `columns` property.

Comment: Thank you, everything is displayed correctly on the user page, and the following error is observed from the administrative side:

Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Comment: Error  in /var/www/u0745416/sveta-webmaster.tk/yii/vendor/omgdef/yii2-multilingual-behavior/src/MultilingualBehavior.phpat line 142

Comment: 1. in /var/www/u0745416/sveta-webmaster.tk/yii/vendor/omgdef/yii2-multilingual-behavior/src/MultilingualBehavior.phpat line 142
133       .  get_class($this->owner) . ' or in the application parameters', 101);
134        }
135 
136        if (array_values($this->languages) !== $this->languages) { //associative array
137            $this->languages = array_keys($this->languages);
138       }
139 
140        $this->languages = array_unique(array_map(function ($language) {
141            return $this->getLanguageBaseName($language);
142        }, $this->languages));
143

Comment: I have never used yii2-multilingual-behavior, It sounds like an issue with the extension code, you could try opening an issue or having a look in the code to see what is allocating the memory.